# Decrypt PKCS7 in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, openssl, pkcs#7

I try to decrypt PKCS7 data, but always receive error `OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7Error - wrong content type` on method `"pkcs7.decrypt(key, cer)"`.

example:

```
cer = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("path/cert.cer"))
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("path/private.key"), "111111")
crypted_data = File.read('path/pkcs7') # contains xml-file and signature "-----BEGIN PKCS7----- ... -----END PKCS7-----"
pkcs7 = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(crypted_data)
decrypted_data = pkcs7.decrypt(key, cer) # error is here
```

need help! how to get data from the encrypted string?

updated:
on bash I can solve this task by following code:

```
openssl smime -verify -noverify -inform PEM -nointern -certfile "path/cert.cer" -CAfile "path/cert.cer" < path/pkcs7
```

returns xml file.

Comment: Run `pkcs7.type` to see whether what you have is `:signed`; if it is, then you need to call `verify` instead of `decrypt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution founded!!!

```
cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
my_cert =  OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("remote.cer"))
signature = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(File.read('pkcs7-resp.file'))
signature.verify([my_cert], cert_store, nil, OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY)
signature.data
```

Comment: as per the method declaration of `verify` method of `PKCS7`, there are 4 args. Can you explain what are those?
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS7.html#method-i-verify