# Decode PKCS7 in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cryptography, pem, pkcs#7

I get a certificate from my client which is a `PKCS7` and I want to decode it.

Usually, I use this website `https://8gwifi.org/PemParserFunctions.jsp` and select the sample file as `PKCS7` and paste the certificate there and it returns the exact result we want.

Now we want to implement that same thing in ruby on rails. How can I do it, I am not able to understand the process of decoding.

Edit 1: Added a sample picture for reference, the output in the image is what I want from the PKCS7 file

[image: pem parser image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decrypt PKCS7 in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477436/decrypt-pkcs7-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: no, the above URL is not the same thing, it says to input certificate too, but if you see my question we are just putting pkcs7 file only.
@Joe refer to the image